# What happens to the reputation earned on Gadgets?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Now that the Gadgets proposal has failed and has been closed, what happens to the reputation we earned?

There are a lot of implications:

- Does the rep. show up in the API?
- The reputation represents time and effort spent. Is that just going to get thrown away?

Comment: Also, what happens to all those shiny badges? Those people did earn them, after all. Will they still count towards the combined flair on Area51, for example?

Comment: Is having rep kept in the API when it isn't a site any better than rep being thrown away though?  You won't be able to take that rep and view anything about it on the site.

Comment: The API for a site will not survive the site.  Generally, it will be down before then, as the site becomes "dead" even if still accessible for a time.  Note that there is no "retired" or "dead" site status in StackAuth.

Comment: I want my rep!!

Comment: Since [the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/) announced some (all?) questions can be migrated to android et al., so if the votes are also transferred the rep will migrate, too. But as I said, **iff**.

Comment: I'm now seeing my Android-related answers from the Gadgets site on the Android site but my Android rep is unchanged.

Comment: @Dan Dyer A recalc might be needed....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep the reputation earned on questions and answers that were migrated to other sites. This works like normal question migration: if you don't have an account on the site it was migrated to, you assume ownership (and reputation) at the time of account creation. Votes on migrated posts are migrated as well, and they are cast by the Community user until they're  "owned".

As for other ways to recognize of the time and energy spent on Gadgets, we're open to suggestions. One idea is a bronze Area 51 badge for users who had over a few hundred rep on Gadgets.

Comment: I'm assuming if someone's Gadgets question gets migrated to Apple or Android they gain its rep on the new site?

Comment: @Simon Brown Yes.

Answer (score 10):

I propose `Zombie Unicorn rep`. The combined rep earned on all failed Stack Exchanges you've participated in. Obviously you would have `Zombie Unicorn badges` too.

[image: Image Source is Hyperlinked]

Comment: So then eventually all of the failed sites get zombicornified?

Comment: That is just sick.

Comment: @George - I have a license to ill.

Comment: It's still sick.

Answer (score 5):

You can exchange your rep for a 1/2 off coupon for pets.com.

Comment: Is this an attempt at humor?

Comment: @George - what do you mean "attempt"?

Comment: "attempt" as in failed :)