# Questions about the Gadgets closure & migration

Tags: discussion, area-51

1. <s>Some, but not all, of my Gadgets reputation got migrated to the Android SE along with my questions and answers.  I [speculated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64669/what-happens-to-the-reputation-earned-on-gadgets/64744#64744) that this is because I got upvotes on Gadgets from users that don't have accounts on Android: correct?</s>  My mistake: I had an upvoted and accepted answer from Gadgets that was re-upvoted and re-accepted by the OP shortly after its migration to Android.
2. Not all of my Android-related posts were migrated to the Android SE.  My highest-voted answer was to a [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/1836) with  (I see now) only an "iphone" tag, so it got migrated to the Apple SE (where I don't have an account).  Is flagging for moderator attention appropriate in this case?
3. [gadgets.stackexchange.com](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com) redirects to the proposal page on Area 51.  Is there a way to access the site, or do we have to wait for the data dump to become available?
4. Do migrated posts count towards commitment on the Android SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Reputation is not migrated between sites.
2. Yes, flag any post that was not migrated and we'll address them.  I have migrated the one you mentioned.
3. There is no way to access the gadgets.stackexchange.com site - it is closed.  The data dump is now available on the [area51 proposal page for gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614).
4. Yes, migrated posts do count towards your commitment on Stack Exchange.