# Migrated questions to Android. Will they be linked to my account?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, user-accounts

I asked and answered a number of questions on the Gadgets site (*Requiescat In Pace*) and they appear to have been migrated to http://android.stackexchange.com.

I was not in the closed beta there (I guess I can wait three more days) but when I get there and create an account, assuming I use the same OpenID credentials as I did on Gadgets, will those questions/answers by linked to my new account?

(Yes, I realize the reputation previously gained on Gadgets does not transfer.)

***Update***: This still hasn't happened, so whatever automated process there is to do this isn't working.

Comment: See this answer to my earlier question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64751/questions-about-the-gadgets-closure-migration/64759#64759

Comment: Are your accounts linked across the sites?

Comment: Yes, although Gadgets was killed before I could create my account on Android. Is that the key issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please flag any posts that were previously yours for moderator attention and we will address them.

Comment: I'll do that, but it'll take some time to find them all.

Comment: This is complete

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal for migrated questions in general.

Comment: I suspect that my question is a duplicate, then.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long does it generally take?