# porting reputation from SO to programmer SE

Tags: feature-request, reputation, integration

As far as I understand, questions about discussion on design is now covered on progSE and so on. I am relatively annoyed by the fact that I can give a >10k support on SO, but on progSE I am at around 150, even if most of the reputation I have on SO is due to questions that may be now a better fit for progSE.

Would it be possible to either :

- migrate question (with associated reputation) to progSE, or
- leave the question, but transfer an arbitrary amount of reputation there, or
- grant at least the power to close on progSE if on SO the rep is >10k.

The point I want to make is that, while I can be a programmer and have high rep on SO and no rep on SF, because I know nothing about sysadmin, in the case of progSE if I am reputable on SO, I am reputable as well on progSE, both as a competence in the topic and in the ordinary administration of it.

Just a thought.

Comment: Mass transfer and re-transfer initiated. mayhem in 3...2..1.

Comment: I'm annoyed that content of SO was divided this way. But it is probably topic for separate question.

Comment: @Ladislav I am annoyed too, and I think it's the worst thing ever made since bagpipes.

Comment: @Ladislav It's a topic that's been covered in about 40 separate questions already

Answer (score 1):

"Reputation" is completely optional and only depends on the number of votes you have received on a given site.

**If this request were to be realized, it would only be fair that *all* questions on Stack Overflow that fit on other sites would transfer reputation, and vice versa.**

Answer (score 0):

If a question is migrated, this also migrates the rep to the other site (question disapears at SE1 and reapears at SE2).

Reputation is linked to questions and answers. There are some bonusses (for example the association of accounts) but the majority is linked so migrating reputation without migrating the linked Q&A is a bit pointless.

Besides, if you already has 10k+ rep on SO, continue the game on programmers. Its fun and keeps you busy.

Comment: Reputation isn't migrated (unless things have changed since this answer) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64751/questions-about-the-gadgets-closure-migration/64759#64759

Comment: ok, it's fun to repost my questions on programmers just to scoop up rep ?

Comment: @Stefano: in theory, it'd be better (for everyone other than you) if they were migrated. However in practice, asking them fresh on P.SE gives you a chance to adjust them for that audience (and yes, it's a different audience) - so you may find that you get a better reception *and* more reputation if you go that way... If you do, my advice is to make it count: find a way to differentiate your repost in some significant way, that way you'll benefit from the rep *and* the answers.