# Are rumors of a film true? I hope so by golly!

Tags: discussion, fun

I heard that there is a film being made. If so, please consider my poster:

[image: Poster 1]

Then people at the Tavern (Lasse V. Karlsen, Yi Jiang, Diago, Tim) had some suggestions:

[image: Poster 2]

Anyway, I hope people make some good suggestions for plot, etc. ... Good luck with filming and stuff.

Aiden

---

Also, Resemblance?
[image: Blues Brothers]

Comment: -1, not enough StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™. How will people know this movie is genuine™?

Comment: @radp that's material for a TV series spinoff. You don't want to use all your material in one movie

Comment: I can't see the pictures... Tell me, is the movie set in Toronto?

Comment: **The Answering of Questions Network: A Michael Bay Film**

Answer (score 114):

In scene 47, [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) finally loses it when the tenth person asks how to parse HTML with regular expressions.

[image: Scene]

Comment: This would make a great spin-off movie. I can hear the [Don LaFontaine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_LaFontaine) voice-over now... "In a world where foolish regex users are unknowingly bringing about the apocalypse, one blue monster must fight to protect our world, and our *sanity* , from Cthulhu's rampaging minions. This December, be sure to see bobince in **HTM-Hell** ! "

Comment: Also, is that a tree pruner in the corner by the door? I think bobince is gonna go on a head-choppin spree!

Answer (score 76):

Kevin Smith as Jeff Atwood

[image: Kevin Smith]
<sub>(source: [examiner.com](http://www.examiner.com/images/blog/EXID15166/images/kevin-smith(5).jpg))</sub>
 [image: Jeff]

Comment: I thought Jeff could talk, though....

Comment: @Michael: obviously, you haven't been listening to the podcast...

Comment: @Shog9, what podcast?

Comment: @Popular Demand http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/

Comment: @Henrik, I'm guessing that Popular was making a sarcastic comment with the intention of pointing out that there hasn't been a new podcast since April.

Comment: @jjnguy maybe.. I don't mind

Comment: @Henrik, yeah, I was referring to the fact that those have been discontinued.

Comment: @Michael Todd Just like Silent Bob, when he does speak it's of huge relevance and importance!

Comment: @AidenB @MichaelT I took way too long to decide whether to do this or not, so @Popular helped me to forget about it. However, here's a short summary: I discovered [Philip Seymour Hoffman](http://www.google.com/search?q="philip+seymour+hoffman") would make a good Jeff, and that Tom Hanks would make [a passable Joel](http://www.philipseymourhoffman.net/gallery/cww7.jpg) (with dark contacts). Alternatively, [Salvatore Inzerillo](http://www.imdb.com/media/rm9928960/nm1935273) has the dark complexion necessary.

Answer (score 69):

They've already opted for a sequel I heard

[image]

<sup>Excuse the poor quality. I'm on Ubuntu right now and GIMP hates me. Or is it the other way round?</sup>

Comment: Meh. Lots of people are fans of Jon Skeet, and lots of people are in the "can we please not treat this guy like a god" camp, but I can't really think of any actual _enemies_ Jon's made.

Comment: That was great!

Comment: @popular demand, I guess if you wanted to make it more accurate you could say "without making a few envy"

Comment: I'll be his enemy! :D I can't think of a reason why yet, but I'm sure if I go read enough of his answers I can figure out _something_ to hate him for.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: I hope it's just a coincidence that you're using the same font (Aller) *and* setting the title so similarly to how I laid out one side of my special needs card! Also, where did you get that hi-res Jon Skeet photo?

Comment: Everyone needs a nemesis...

Comment: It just occurred to me that this is based off an actual real-life movie poster. **That means I'm a real computer programmer now, right?**

Comment: @BoltClock: I thought this was a play on some phrase, and then yesterday I actually saw a poster just like it in the parking lot.

Answer (score 59):

The GEICO gecko as Bill the Lizard
[image][image]

Comment: +1 - It will be like a twisted alice in wonderland

Comment: @Aiden, I thought they already made that; it was called _Alice in Wonderland_.

Comment: It's true... they always do get someone more handsome to play you in the film.

Answer (score 38):

Mike Myers as mmyers.

[image: Mike Myers]  [image: mmyers]

This one should be obvious.

Comment: +1 Ah, I see the resemblance!

Comment: Mike Myers as himself.  FTFY.

Comment: NOT FUNNY.​​​​​

Comment: @Michael, is this the first time you have seen this?

Comment: @jjn, [yes](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/266006#266006)

Comment: For the record, I refuse to answer to "Mike" unless it's someone I know well.

Comment: @Michael, good to know.

Comment: @Mic: If they know you well, don't they know you dislike it?

Answer (score 37):

**Scenes**:

[image]

Meta users protest the decision to [withdraw per-site domain names](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

[image]

A [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/creative-commons-data-dump-oct-10/) on its way to the clearbits data center

[image]

[Stackheads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/what-should-the-users-of-meta-stackoverflow-com-be-referred-to-as) trailing the Truck transferring Meta.SO from Corvallis, Oregon, to New York City. It is said sixteen great new API tools were conceived during the journey

Comment: Hahahaha, that IS what data dumps look like :D

Comment: Thanks for the lolz Pekka.  I'm gonna get back to work now...

Answer (score 36):

Gary Busey as the Evil Unicorn Overlord.

[image]

(Credits: [image 1](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jawboneradio/484658837/in/photostream/), [image 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:GaryBuseyOct07.jpg).)

Comment: and appearing in [ **this answer** ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64669/what-happens-to-the-reputation-earned-on-gadgets/64677#64677)

Answer (score 34):

Ok, so it's recycling an old image, and I think we've got a different top seven now, but what the hell...

[image: Jon Skeet and the League of Justice]

Comment: I don't think Marc Gravell appreciates where you put his head.

Comment: Well all he has to do is get another 60k rep and I'll swap him and Jon over. :)

Comment: +1 just for the effort involved :)

Answer (score 27):

An Oktoberfest "[Maß](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%C3%9F)" as [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov).

[image]   [image]

Comment: That's paradise!

Comment: +1 Good strategy for attracting ... votes.

Comment: Photographer: 'scuse me darling, could you move that beer away from your mouth a bit?

Comment: The picture's from The Boston Globe's Big Picture blog - [Octoberfest 2010](http://www.boston.com/bigpicture/2010/09/oktoberfest_2010.html)

Comment: @jinguy: Mmmm *both*.

Comment: @Pekka: I'm floored. That is the same picture I used as a humorous intro for a presentation I had to do in grad school. And BTW, I'm told those are the demitasse mugs favored by the ladies in Germany — the men, of course, wouldn't be caught dead drinking from anything so petite. *Nicht wahr?*

Comment: @Robusto ahahaha! Yeah, the picture seems to have some notoriety (although I think it's not that old yet). I can't comment on the Maß size issue - where I live, we drink beer from slim tiny [Kölsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6lsch_(beer)) glasses :)

Answer (score 23):

I was going to leave well enough alone. I really was. But then I heard that the film will feature a special guest appearance by Shog9... **as himself!**

[image: shog9 and his regeneration tube whatsit]

Comment: +1 for Popular getting involved.

Comment: Nice try, but that looks more like a shaved Welbog. WHAT HAVE YOU BEEN DOING WITH WELBOG, POPS?

Comment: Power rangers :)

Answer (score 21):

Don't forget about [waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles)!

[image] [image]

I think Seth Rogen is perfect for the role.

Comment: This is a fun game, right!?

Comment: http://twitter.com/#!/samsaffron/status/26800403696 :)

Comment: @NullUser: Right you are. I guess I mixed up the spelling with [Joe Rogan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Rogan).

Comment: wow, even he could play waffles in a pinch: http://topcultured.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/rogan1.jpg

Comment: @Popular: Actually, he might work better for Marc. I've been having a little trouble [coming up with a good one for him](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67008/are-rumors-of-a-film-true-i-hope-so-by-golly/67036#67036).

Answer (score 19):

The role of Joel seems to be hard to fill

[image]

Comment: I was thinking Brad Garrett, but I couldn't find a photo of Garrett where he wasn't either laughing crazily or doing this weird half-smile/half-frown thing.

Comment: http://www.celebritywonder.com/picture/Brad_Garrett/BradGarrett_Granitz_12605379.jpg

Comment: Did you make those percentages up, or is there some sort of program that computes face similar-ness?

Comment: @Henrik, yeah, that's the weird expression I'm talking about.

Comment: I think Bertie - the former Prime Minister of Ireland - will be busy doing ads and writing columns for a local tabloid. (It's ridiculous, really)

Comment: What's the Taoiseach doing there?

Answer (score 13):

It was a quiet day on Stack Overflow. The trolls haven't left their puny grotto's and the Spammers focused on other parts of the Internet. A seasoned user with 9970 rep was looking for an easy question to get the three upvotes needed to access the wild secrets of the moderator tools. And then it happened.

He refreshed for the next time and a new question was shown on top of the list. He opened the question and read it. His eyes widened while his brain tries to figure out an answer. This couldn't be that hard. But the question was gibberish. Well not exactly gibberish, it was incomprehensible, but on a different scale. First he thought about utter nonsense and his mouse moved to the close button. But then he started wondering. Is this real nonsense, or am I too stupid to understand this question. But I can't be stupid with 9970, almost 10k rep.

In the mean time the question started to collect votes. Upvotes, downvotes, close and reopen votes. A wild discussion started with comments. 10, 20, 100 comments. Respectable members where caught calling each other names. And the question collected the third gold badge for favorites.

He saw it all and couldn't understand. The question was too hard for his brain, but he still wanted to get those three upvotes. And while his brain worked hard to find an answer. He heard a loud bang. And then nothing. The question that kills was born, and he was just the first victim.

Comment: We should call it "All That BLITters".

Comment: Haha.. this is lovely.

Comment: That is Priceless!

Answer (score 12):

Every film needs a scrappy underdog fighting to be #1:

[image] [image]

[Dougie Poynter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dougie_Poynter) as [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell).

This match was found courtesy of the [MyHeritage.com face recognition tool](http://celebrity.myheritage.com/FP/Company/try-face-recognition.php). It gives a 62% match for the above, but interestingly enough gives a 59% match for [Linus Torvalds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds)!

[image]

Comment: No, not Linus. See [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67008/are-rumors-of-a-film-true-i-hope-so-by-golly/67035#67035) for a Linux-like alternative :)

Comment: That's a pretty good match, but he isn't even an actor...

Comment: @jjnguy: Yeah, he's a musician, but he's pretty much the best match that site found. I think Marc kinda bears some resemblance to Edward Furlong too.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can get on board that idea.

Comment: Wait.... Scrappy underdog? What now? Must... Resist... Moderator-tools-of-death...

Answer (score 9):

[image]

---

Some people don't think Tux and TV don't go together. To that I reply:

[image]

*^--- How's **that** for using the Gimp :)*

Comment: -2? I guess there must be a few Windows and Mac users here :P

Comment: My guess is that some people frown on self-promotion.

Comment: @gno: I bet if Jon Skeet posted an answer *he* would get upvotes.

Comment: @gno: And besides... this is Friday - it's all in good humor.

Comment: Jon Skeet just has to blink and he gets upvotes.

Comment: Actually, he gets the same number of votes whether he blinks or not. He even gets votes for [flicking his fingers](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/1994-11-23/) (see the next strip, too).

Comment: @Mark: Haha... that's so true.

Comment: It's not the self-promotion I have a problem with, it's the fact that Tux doesn't exactly epitomize Hollywood, or even daytime television.

Comment: @Aarobot don't you dare put the "Direct to DVD" stamp on poor Tux!

Comment: @Pekka: I'm afraid I don't quite get that one.

Comment: @George "Direct to DVD" is a term from the Film industry when a production is targeted to go directly to DVD without being released in the cinema, or on TV first. (Not all Direct to DVD content is bad, but much of it is, which is why it has a reputation of low quality)

Comment: @Pekka: Oh sorry. I meant that I knew what 'Direct-to-DVD' meant... I just didn't get the humor of it :)

Comment: @George no real humour in it as such :) Just responding to Aarobot's claim that Tux is not Hollywood material.

Answer (score -2):

yes they are ... m. night shyamalan will be directing.

Comment: no way...he has been cranking out pieces of junk for years.