# Careers 2.0 logo is wrong

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs, logo

[The logo with the space shuttle, the one that tries to imply going up, UP and to the SKY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J3Vg.jpg)!!!
Is wrong, as the space shuttle program is currently grounded.
Can we change it, may be to one of the Soviet/European space crafts?

[image: Logo in line]

Comment: Link to the logo?

Comment: So, uhm, how many soviet space crafts were launched recently?

Comment: In stackoverflow.com the career2.0 ad with the shuttle :-D

Comment: @balpha One several weeks ago, went to the international space station ;-) http://www.cfnews13.com/article/news/2012/january/374555/Soyuz-rocket-blasts-off-toward-space-station-loaded-with-new-supplies

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rC5KxexbDEM

Comment: @balpha - yeah, makes me laugh every time, besides, I did write soviet/europian and not just soviet

Comment: @balpha why the spanish version? :D

Comment: @Alenanno The choice of Simpson clips is pretty low on YouTube :) And in this case, it didn't really matter

Comment: I figure the image has more to do with the rocket than with its payload.  The US shuttle program may be grounded, but rockets still... rocket.  Upward.  Really fast.  I think the analogy holds.

Comment: Why not just hire [Zlad](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKO9h-gG4Qg) as spokesperson?

Comment: @Won't put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Deferred until such a time when space shuttle launches are not awesome.

Comment: I just checked, rocket launches are still awesome.

Comment: Just checked again, they're still awesome.

Answer (score 4):

The space shuttle program was incredibly successful.  It was a design that, with minor modifications, worked very well for **thirty years**.  They had 135 launches and 2 accidents.

When the first space shuttle launched:

- MS-DOS 1.0 wouldn't be released for 5 more months
- It would be more than a month before the first US Patent for software was granted
- The Commodore 64 was over a year away
- BASIC didn't exist
- The first IBM PC hadn't been released yet

Major companies like Logitech, Adaptech, SGI, Maxtor, Symantec, Compaq, Adobe, Iomega, and Dell didn't yet exist, and CAT1 wiring was 4 years in the future.

The last mission completed **7 months ago.**

So, yeah, I think a picture of a shuttle launch can be interpreted as a sign of success.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think [the ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J3Vg.jpg) works because there is a space shuttle program currently working.

The Area51 drawings don't imply that we are working with aliens... (...right?)

Comment: We don't? Who keeps visiting me in my sleep then?

Comment: @animuson I'm not sure I want to know. :D

Comment: @animuson - The bug fluffy blue guy and the green one with one eye.

Comment: @cdeszaq That makes sense...

Comment: @Robert good point, he's a homicidal maniac anyway! http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67041/138112

Comment: I would like to think you are wrong in this assumption. You know what they say about assumptions,(...right?)

Comment: @ItayMoav Yes yes I do!