# Answer corrupted

Tags: support, specific-answer

Not sure if this is the right place but the [1st answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/21960) to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) appears terribly corrupted. Apart from that the readable part of the answer reads very opinionated.

Comment: Yes, congratulations, you just met the most corrupted post in the history of the network 8)

Comment: Worth reading for you as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182189/152859

Comment: Indeed. What is probably missing is the accompanying cartoon properly depicting the state of the author at the time of writing :)

Comment: What, like [this photo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67041)?

Comment: Yeah, exactly that :)

Comment: I'd say, use it as obligatory link for all those closed questions ...

Comment: That one is priceless! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67008/are-rumors-of-a-film-true-i-hope-so-by-golly/67045#67045[link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67008/are-rumors-of-a-film-true-i-hope-so-by-golly/67045#67045)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is not corrupted.

The author pulled in various memes to create one of the most beautiful answers of all time. It is a piece of textual performance art. Bobince wrote it after returning from the pub one night and finding one parse-HTML-with-regex question too many.

The unicode tricks to *appear* corrupted specifically refer to the [Zalgo meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/zalgo).

See also: [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: -1 Pretty sure the answer *is* corrupted. Can't you see?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Do you *want* me to ask Bobince on Monday about this? He's at the desk right across from me.. He has a direct hotlink to Cthulhu, these days..

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to offend anyone's feelings

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: No offense taken here. I'm sure Bobince will find it totally hilarious when I tell him. :-P

Comment: This comment is not ส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ヾ( ´ ▽ `)ノส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ corrupted!