# Atheism is being closed 3/18; does that mean at 00:00 after 3/17 or 00:00 after 3/18?

Tags: support, terminology

I know this may seem like a dumb question, but to clarify [[Atheism.se](http://atheism.stackexchange.com) is being] "closed on 3/18." Does that mean tomorrow morning, it will be locked; or does it mean that at the end of tomorrow it will be locked?

I just posted a bounty and want to know when I need to award it by.

Comment: This does not bode well for my Agnosticism proposal.

Comment: Wow. Here I thought Twitter's "change" link besides its "world trends" is a pretty breath-taking feat of Web 2.0 (remember how hard it was to change world trends in the old days?), but along comes SE, Inc. and, without much ado, closes Atheism as if it was a mere website. I'm impressed.

Comment: I thought the skeptics SE would be a much better choice, as it encompasses this topic and many more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably during the US workday on 3/18, which would be starting around 16:00 UTC, as this is probably a manual process.

> I just posted a bounty and want to know when I need to award it by.

It really doesn't matter, since all reputation will be gone anyway.

Comment: Do you have a settled link to an explanation or discussion on the reputation from sites going away?

Comment: @mfg [See here as to what happened with Gadgets](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64669/what-happens-to-the-reputation-earned-on-gadgets). Since there's very little, if anywhere, that Atheism can be migrated to... it's pretty much gone.

Comment: This is correct. Without a lot of Pomp and Circumstance, I intended that the site would be closed sometime during the workday, Friday.